# TinyButStrong - PHP template engine and OpenTBS docx file conversion to html

Tags: php, openxml, opentbs

Is it possible from `.dox` file (or `OpenXML` format) save as `html` code, modify it with TinyMCE and convert back to previuos file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nis not the propose of TinyButStrong and OpenTBS to convert files. They cannot do that.

This type of conversion is very hard to perfom. As far as I know, only OpenOffice ans Ms Office can seriously convert such files.